# model value not geting in controller display blank?

Tags: model

My config file is Contact/Contact/etc/config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
            <modules>
            <Contact_Contact>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Contact_Contact>
            </modules>
            <frontend>
                        <routers>
                                <contact>
                                    <use>standard</use>
                                    <args>
                                    <module>Contact_Contact</module>
                                    <frontName>contact</frontName>
                                    </args>
                                </contact>
                        </routers>
            <layout>
                    <updates>
                            <contact>
                            <file>contactUs.xml</file>
                            </contact>
                    </updates>
            </layout>
            </frontend>
<global>

            <models>
                        <contact>
                        <!-- Init model for mymod module -->
                        <class>Contact_Contact_Model</class>
                        <!-- Init db config handler for mymod models -->
                        <resourceModel>Contact_mysql4</resourceModel>
                        </contact>

            <!-- declaring model vs db table relation -->
                        <contact_mysql4>
                        <class>Mypackage_Mymod_Model_Mysql4</class>
                        <!-- declate table test -->
                        <entities>
                        <contact>
                        <table>contact</table>
                        </contact>
                        </entities>
                        <!-- -/- -->
                        </contact_mysql4>
            <!-- -/- -->
            </models>


<!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
        <resources>
                <contact_setup>
                <setup>
                <module>contact_contact</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
                </contact_setup>
                    <contact_write>
                    <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                    </contact_write>
                    <contact_read>
                    <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                    </contact_read>
        </resources>

        <blocks>
                    <contact>
                    <class>Contact_Contact_Block</class>
                    </contact>
        </blocks>    

        <helpers>
                    <contact>
                    <class>contact_contact_Helper</class>
                    </contact>
        </helpers>

</global>
</config>
```

contact.php file contact/contact/model/contact.php

```
  <?php

class Contact_Contact_Model_Contact extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

    public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('contact/contact');
     }
}

?>
```

Contact\Contact\Model\Mysql4\contact.php

```
<?php
class Contact_Contact_Model_Mysql4_Contact extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('contact/contact', 'contact_id');
     }
}

?>
```

Contact\Contact\Model\Mysql4\contact\collection.php

```
<?php

class Contact_Contact_Model_Mysql4_Contact_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 {
     public function _construct()
     {
        // parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('contact/contact');
     }


}
```

Contact\Contact\controllers\IndexController.php

```
class Contact_Contact_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{


          public function saveAction()
            {
                //on recuperes les données envoyées en POST
               echo $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
               echo $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
               echo $subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('subject');
               echo $message = $this->getRequest()->getPost('message');



               $collection = Mage::getModel('contact/contact')->getCollection();

               echo "<pre>";
               print_R($collection);





            }
}
```

Not any value getiing or inserted using controller and model

Comment: Did you flush cache? Also where is your db save function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see an error in your resource model configuration in your module's `config.xml` file. So change it likethis.

```
<contact_mysql4>
     <class>Contact_Contact_Model_Mysql4</class>
     ....

</contact_mysql4>
```

Plus

Almost all files you have wrong names. So correct names/path are

```
Contact\Contact\Model\Mysql4\Contact\Collection.php

Contact\Contact\Model\Mysql4\Contact.php

Contact/Contact/Model/Contact.php
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get data from contact Table?

Comment: Also can you tell me How to inseted data in contact table field is name,email,subject,message

Comment: to get a value : `$item = Mage::getModel('model_alias/entity')->load($id);$item->getData('field');`

Comment: please google it. you will get lot of tutorials. If nothing helped, feel free to post a question here. Always remember to put relevant codes with your question

Comment: If my answer helped you to resolve this particular issue, then accept it.